# The font attribute not overriding theme

Tags: android, xml

Adding fontFamily in the view in the layout doesn't effect anything , it should override the theme as explained by the instructor, it should override because attribute have highest priority .

```
<TextView
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        />
```

Styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lobster</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lobster</item>
</style>
```

But the font attribute doesn't override

Answer (score 1):

Use `@font/monospace` inside TextView

```
<TextView
    android:fontFamily="@font/monospace"
    />
```

Comment: didn't work, the monospace is a default font provided . and it don't need @font/monospace